# books on very large scale linear optimization

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, linear-programming, textbook-recommendation, books

Recently in my material science research, I have encountered problems of very large scale linear optimization. I read the introductory book "Introduction to Linear Optimization (Athena Scientific Series in Optimization and Neural Computation, 6)" and I wish to read further trying to resolve the very large scale linear programming problem I encountered.

What books would you suggest me to read to further develop my knowledge? Thank you:)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/184224/current-status-of-combinatorial-optimization-solvers

Comment: Can you quantify "very large scale"?

Comment: Are you interested in Linear Programs or also Mixed Integer Linear Programs? Can you quantify the usual number of variables and/or constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Marti, Reinelt: *The Linear Ordering Problem*. This books gives an up-to-date overview.